# positioning image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a background image which I want to put on a selector #page_wrap, but I would like to overlap that background image on another div which sits above it, by about 20 pixels.

I was wondering how you do this with javascript?

As its a CMS I'm unable to split the image into 2 and use a background image for the div above it so thought with javascript I could accomplish this, but I've forgotten how to do it.

Hope you can help,

Kind Regards

Comment: Do you really need JS? Can you post the code?

Comment: I haven't written any code, I've just got a div on a CMS that I can't edit, so I want to move the div directly below it up, because I have an image where I want it to overlap slightly, so yes I guess I do need javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery?

```
$("#page_wrap").css("margin-top","-20px");
```

Comment: Sorry for the original answer I didn't read the question properly :)

Comment: Sorry I edited the answer my original answer was CSS version... not with Javascript as requested :)

Comment: I think you mean .css('margin-top','-20px') -- there's no jQuery .style() method and it's margin-top instead of top-margin.

Comment: Haha yeah I had a dim moment thanks :) its too hot in the office today ;)

Answer (score 1):

> "I would like to overlap that background image on another div which sits above it, by about 20 pixels."

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/yADGy/

If you have the option to just edit the CSS I would add this...

```
#page_wrap {
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

If you have to use jQuery then try this...

```
$('#page_wrap').css({
    'margin-top' : '-20px',
    'position' : 'relative',
    'z-index' : '1'
});
```

If this isn't what you're trying to do please elaborate some.